# populating a text box on a form - oracle

Tags: oracle, builder

I am using application builder in oracle - and I have a create new record form for the opening times of a cinema.

Basically at the moment I have it so you can put ina cinema id from a cinema table, but the problem is whith that you need to know the id - so its not very user friendly. I would like this id to be dynamically be put in to the form somehow by slecting the cinema name from a dropdown (I have managed to include the cinema dropdown)

How can i populate the form with the respective id based upn the choice of the select box in application builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Oracle Application Express, which has a component called application builder?

A typical select list query would be:

```
select cinema_name, cinema_id
from cinemas
order by cinema_name;
```

That will display a list of cinema names to the user, and when the pick one populate the item value with the cinema ID.  In HTML terms it constructs a SELECT tag like this:

```
<select id="P1_CINEMAS">
  <option value="11">Ashtead</option>
  <option value="23">Birmingham</option>
  <option value="72">Croydon</option>
</select>
```

If the user chooses "Croydon" from the above list, the value "72" will be posted to the database.